# BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM with BOOST_PP_SEQ_ADD in nested macro?

Tags: c++, boost, macros

I'm confident that you can use `BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM(BOOST_PP_ADD(n,1),sequence)`, but I can't quite seem to pinpoint why the `EXTRACT` macro below is unable to compile with "too few arguments provided to function like macro".

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/seq/elem.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/repetition/repeat.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/seq/size.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/stringize.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/control/iif.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/arithmetic/mod.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/logical/not.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/arithmetic/add.hpp>

#include <iostream>

// attempt 2.7 beta
#define EXTRACT(z, n, args) \
    BOOST_PP_IIF(\
        /* on every third index */ \
        BOOST_PP_NOT(BOOST_PP_MOD(n,3)),\
        /* check the flag */ \
        BOOST_PP_IIF(BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM(n,args),\
            /*BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM(n,args),*/ \
            BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM(BOOST_PP_ADD(n,1),args),\
            "narp"\
        ),\
    )

// absurd wrapper for extract
#define ALL_ARGS(args) BOOST_PP_REPEAT(BOOST_PP_SEQ_SIZE(args),EXTRACT,args)

// every third element is a "flag"
//                   v          v
#define MY_SEQUENCE (1)(int)(z)(0)(float)(y)

int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
    std::cout <<
        BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(ALL_ARGS(MY_SEQUENCE))
        << std::endl;
}
```

The example is far from what I want to do with this, but right now I'm just trying to figure out how to get the actual `int` and `z` or `float` and `y`.

If it matters, the actual goal is instantiating templates.  I have a sequence of template classes, but am unable to figure out how to instantiate

```
//                          vvvvvvvvvvvv
template <class X> void foo(SomeThing<X> varName);
```

So the flag here is letting me know if `SomeThing` needs `<X>` or not.  Perhaps there is an easier way to approach this?  I'm already inside a `BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH` for the classes in the template, so the only thing I could figure out how to do was pass this ugly arguments sequence along.  FWIW I know `int<X>` isn't valid, this is just testing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Diagnostic hint

In general preprocessor macros are easier to debug using the preprocessor than they are "tiny programs".  For example, what you have here requires a full compilation and launching to see an issue; but if you comment out `#include <iostream>` and `#include <boost/preprocessor/stringize.hpp>`, and replace the entire main function with just `ALL_ARGS(MY_SEQUENCE)`, then you can simply launch your preprocessor and see its output directly; no compilation/running necessary.

Not only is this quicker, but you get to play on a token level to produce things that can help you, without having to worry about producing things that will compile.

### Tracing the issue

Using the transformation above I performed a single expansion of `ALL_ARGS` (after reproducing the problem) by changing the argument `EXTRACT` to `EXTRACT_`.  [This iterated just fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/69a55f9a5d4c85ed).  Next I changed `ALL_ARGS` to the output of the expansion, breaking each `EXTRACT_` on separate lines and adding an artificial label, then changed `EXTRACT_` back to `EXTRACT`; e.g.:

```
0_  EXTRACT(2, 0, (1)(int)(z)(0)(float)(y))
1_  EXTRACT(2, 1, (1)(int)(z)(0)(float)(y))
...
```

Running this through the preprocessor again showed that all expansions were fine, [except for the sixth one](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/af14d21a92198d9a):

```
5_  EXTRACT(2, 5, (1)(int)(z)(0)(float)(y))
```

This in mind it was easy to spot.  The problem is indeed with this part:

```
BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM(BOOST_PP_ADD(n,1),args)
```

...when `EXTRACT` is run with n=5, this amounts to `BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM(6, (1)(int)(z)(0)(float)(y))`.  There's no element offset 6 here, so the macro crumbles.  Mind you, `BOOST_PP_NOT(BOOST_PP_MOD(5,3))` is `0`, so the outer `BOOST_PP_IIF` doesn't *select* the inner one, but it still must *evaluate* it.

### Alternate approach

> Perhaps there is an easier way to approach this?

Absolutely.  Use a different data structure.  Here, your strategy is to use a sequence of size 3*n for some n, then pick out every 3 items in the sequence.

With some fiddling you can surely do this, but the entire reason you need to is because you don't really have a series of *items*... rather, you have a series of *sets of 3 items*.  If you change your data structure to a sequence of 3-tuples, this becomes *much much* easier; all you need is an `IIF`, a `FOR_EACH`, and a couple of worker macros:

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/control/iif.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/seq/for_each.hpp>
#define MY_SEQUENCE ((1,int,z))((0,float,y))
#define APPLY_EXTRACT(r,data,elem) EXTRACT elem
#define EXTRACT(FLAG_,TYPE_,PNAME_) BOOST_PP_IIF(FLAG_, TYPE_, "narp")
#define ALL_ARGS(args) BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(APPLY_EXTRACT, _, MY_SEQUENCE)

ALL_ARGS(MY_SEQUENCE)
```

[See this on stacked-crooked](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aa049880c9d94cbe)

Comment: Thank you **very** much for walking me through **how** to debug this!  The `-E` and `-P` flags in particular are news to me, and **far more effective**!!!  In hindsight, it makes sense *why* boost still needs to evaluate everything regardless of the `IIF` condition.  This answer is exceptional, these new techniques have greatly increased my metaprogramming capabilities and I shall never attempt to debug my macros by printing again!!! THANK YOU :)  As a quick followup, changing to `EXTRACT_` is just to double check the first expansion, there's nothing special about the `_` right?

Comment: @sjm324 It does serve the purpose of checking the expansion, but it's also significant that the preprocessor itself performed that expansion step.  And yes, the only thing special about `EXTRACT_` is that it's not defined, so there's no further expansion.